# Pdo error with invalid parameters

Tags: php, sql, pdo, crud

I have an error since yesterday on my crud and I'm becoming crazy.
For editing entries in my database, I have two files:

- **edit.php** with the editing form identified by the parameter id
  [see code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aq8Eu.png)
- **doedit.php** that actually modify the entry in database
  [see code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9LXJ6.png)

and the warning returned is : 
PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined in **/Users/joseteixeira/Sites/TP-PHP/admin/doedit.php** on line **47**

Any idea on what might have gone wrong ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP PDO Error - : Invalid parameter number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38503061/php-pdo-error-invalid-parameter-number)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your doedit.php, you have this line in your query:

```
`p` = p,
```

Change this to:

```
`p` = :p,
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error says that "parameter" was not defined, so kindly remove parameter from bindValue function.

```
$statement->bindValue(":slug", $slug);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your SQL statement please use

p = :p

You have missed: while assigning value.

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to put a : before p (should be :p) on 28 number line in your doedit file.